# Installation a tool on linux having tar.uue extension

Tags: linux, installation, tar

I have to install one tool on linux platform which have tar.uue (genscanlinux.tar.uue) extension. I am unable to unzip it. Kindly tell me how can i unzip and install it?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: ZIP archives generally have the .zip extension. Searching for ".uue" hints that it's not a ZIP archive, and will mention the decoding tool as answered by @Jaguar. (You can use this for identifying other unknown file extensions as well)

Comment: Thankyou Piskvor, i didnt know decoding system in files other than zip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To decode a file with .uue extension use the following command:

```
uudecode genscanlinux.tar.uue
```

after this you will get genscanlinux.tar. You can unzip it using this command:

```
tar -zxvf genscanlinux.tar
```

After this you will get extracted file in the current directory.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Jaguar for providing me solution. I run uudecode command on my fedora14 , it first asked me to install "sharutils". I installed it and than uudecode able to decode it.